# Prefered rank in Wikidata not working properly for population in some cases?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

So I'm currently working on a project where Im using data that I'm getting from Wikidata and I noticed a lot of duplicate elements in my database. Reason for that is that I'm receiving population numbers for different points in time.

I've read that Wikidata has rankings for statements with multipile values and for the population property that seems to be the most recent value-which is true for about 99.9% of the entries. What I don't understand is why it doesn't work for the other 0.1%.

One example would be: [Wikidata query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20%3Fsettlement%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fsettlement%20%3D%20wd%3AQ515%20%7C%7C%20%3Fsettlement%20%3D%20wd%3AQ15284%29%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation.%20%0A%20%20filter%20%28%3Fcity%3Dwd%3AQ1658752%29%20%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20.%0A%09%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D)

The same happens for example with the elements

- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1073108
- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1146813
- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q532037

and I have no idea why.

I've already tried the solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181713/sparql-query-to-get-only-results-with-the-most-recent-date) but it didn't change the result.

Any ideas?

---

Edit based on the filter option from the thread: [wikidata query 2](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20%3Fsettlement%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fsettlement%20%3D%20wd%3AQ515%20%7C%7C%20%3Fsettlement%20%3D%20wd%3AQ15284%29%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation.%20%0A%20%20filter%20%28%3Fcity%3Dwd%3AQ1658752%29%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3Ap1082%2Fpq%3A585%20%3Fdate%20%0A%20%20filter%20%28%3Fdate%20%3E%20%3Fpopulation%29%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20.%0A%09%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D)

Edit 2: [Full query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fsettlement%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ515%29%20%28wd%3AQ15284%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fsettlement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%20FILTER%20%28%3Fcountry%20%3Dwd%3AQ183%29%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%5B%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%3B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate1%20%5D%20%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%5B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate2%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fdate2%20%3E%20%3Fdate1%29%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1705%20%3Fnative%20%7D.%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%202000%29%0A%7D)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49066390/7879193

Comment: I tried that already and that didnt work

Comment: @Wajora "didn't work" is not a good description for what you tried exactly, what you got and what you expected...please provide details to reproduce it

Comment: @sIm sorry, I edited the post and added what I tried based on your suggestion. if I understood your suggestion correct this is what shoudlve fixed it but it still selects duplicates

Comment: Your revised query includes `filter (?date > ?population)` which seems nonsensical. I suggest you also rework your indentation to make the query structure clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Wikidata properties are processed by [PreferentialBot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:PreferentialBot) ([source code](https://github.com/smalyshev/pywikibot-core/blob/prefer3/prefer.py)).

In short, the bot makes the most recent statements [preferred](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Statement_representation), hence making them [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements).

Sometimes the bot does not process statements for a property. For example, the bot doesn't process items that have statements without respective qualifiers.

In your particular case:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population ?date ?rank WHERE {
  VALUES (?settlement) {(wd:Q515) (wd:Q15284)}
  VALUES (?city) {(wd:Q1658752)}
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?settlement . 
  ?city p:P1082 ?statement .
  ?statement ps:P1082 ?population .
  ?statement wikibase:rank ?rank
  OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P585 ?date }  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }   
} ORDER by ?date
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fdate%20%3Frank%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fsettlement%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ515%29%20%28wd%3AQ15284%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcity%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ1658752%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fsettlement%20.%20%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20wikibase%3Arank%20%3Frank%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D%20ORDER%20by%20%3Fdate%0A)

Results:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|    city     | cityLabel | population |        date          |         rank        |
+-------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| wd:Q1658752 | Kagan     |      86745 |                      | wikibase:NormalRank |
| wd:Q1658752 | Kagan     |      17656 | 1939-01-01T00:00:00Z | wikibase:NormalRank |
| wd:Q1658752 | Kagan     |      21103 | 1959-01-01T00:00:00Z | wikibase:NormalRank |
| wd:Q1658752 | Kagan     |      34117 | 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z | wikibase:NormalRank |
| wd:Q1658752 | Kagan     |      41565 | 1979-01-01T00:00:00Z | wikibase:NormalRank |
| wd:Q1658752 | Kagan     |      48054 | 1989-01-01T00:00:00Z | wikibase:NormalRank |
+-------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Would you prefer the most recent statement or the "eternal" one?

This is how you can find the most recent population:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population WHERE {
  VALUES (?settlement) {(wd:Q515) (wd:Q15284)}
  VALUES (?city) {(wd:Q1658752)}
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?settlement . 
  ?city p:P1082 [ ps:P1082 ?population; pq:P585 ?date1 ]  
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?city p:P1082 [ pq:P585 ?date2 ]
    FILTER (?date2 > ?date1) }
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }   
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fsettlement%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ515%29%20%28wd%3AQ15284%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcity%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ1658752%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fsettlement%20.%20%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%5B%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%3B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate1%20%5D%20%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%5B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate2%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fdate2%20%3E%20%3Fdate1%29%20%7D%0ASERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D)

This is how you can find the "eternal" one:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population WHERE {
  VALUES (?settlement) {(wd:Q515) (wd:Q15284)}
  VALUES (?city) {(wd:Q1658752)}
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?settlement . 
  ?city p:P1082 ?statement .
  ?statement ps:P1082 ?population .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?statement pq:P585 []}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }   
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fsettlement%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ515%29%20%28wd%3AQ15284%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcity%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ1658752%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fsettlement%20.%20%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP585%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%7D%20ORDER%20by%20%3Ftime)

---

In fact, almost 70% (not 0.1%) of entries with the `P1082` property do not have preferred statements for this property. Your should rather mean entries with the `P1082` property that have more than one truthy statement for this property. Recall that:

> Truthy statements represent statements that have the best non-deprecated rank for given property. Namely, if there is a preferred statement for property `P2`, then only preferred statements for `P2` will be considered truthy. Otherwise, all normal-rank statements for `P2` are considered truthy.

And yes, about 0.5% entries that have `P1082`-statements have two or more truthy `P1082`-statements.

Comment: I realized that I still didnt quite understand why the preferentialbot doesnt process the date in this case. You said it doesnt process items that have statements without respective qualifiers, but isnt the point in time date a qualifier in this case?

Comment: Statement with value 86,745 has no P585 qualifier: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1658752#Q1658752$BADE429F-21B8-44EE-98BC-F5A2ABEE4988

Comment: @Wajora, hence, the bot doesn't process all statements with P1082 property. You could edit my answer in order to make that more clear, my English is poor...

Comment: For comparison, replace `wd:Q1658752` with `wd:Q887` in my first query.