# SPARQL - How to get only newest entities

Tags: database, sparql, rdf

In my triple store i've a collection of schema:CreativeWork which has the property schema:version and schema:dateCreated.
Now i want to get all schema:CreativeWork but only the newest ones.
My sample:

```
PREFIX schema: <https://schema.org/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE { 
    ?subject rdf:type schema:CreativeWork .     
    ?subject schema:identifier ?identifier .
    ?subject schema:version ?version .
    ?subject schema:dateCreated ?dateCreated .
    OPTIONAL {?subject schema:about/schema:name ?name .}
    FILTER( ?identifier = "46d8b7abfec44865a567ea04e385661b" ) .
} LIMIT 10
```

How do i manage to query only the latest version?

executable sample: https://api.triplydb.com/s/rLq4V-JgS

Note: `FILTER( ?identifier = "46d8b7abfec44865a567ea04e385661b" ) .` is just to make it easier.

Comment: The [sample](https://api.triplydb.com/s/n6qyvIZXa) with a filter as descibed in [SPARQL query to get only results with the most recent date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181713/sparql-query-to-get-only-results-with-the-most-recent-date)

Comment: a [sample](https://api.triplydb.com/s/cQ6W-Y7Kb) that gets the max version by identifier

Comment: is your comment the answer to your question?

Comment: no, it isn't. just some hints. i still did not have the solution.

Comment: is this your own dataset? Why are the literals all strings? This makes it really difficult to use an efficient filter. While I understand, that depending on the version scheme an integer might not be feasible, for date literals not using the appropriate datatype makes the data somewhat less expressive and inconvenient to use.

Comment: in theory, adding `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?subject2 schema:identifier ?identifier . ?subject2 schema:version ?dateCreated2 FILTER(?dateCreated2 > ?dateCreated)}` would just return the one with the latest creation date, it doesn't work on your data because string comparison is lexicographically. It also leads to a timeout

Comment: the same resource is identified by the identifier, right?

Comment: here is something that doesn't timeout: `SELECT DISTINCT * {
  
  {SELECT ?identifier (max(?dateCreated) as ?latestDate)
WHERE { 
 ?subject rdf:type schema:CreativeWork .   
   ?subject schema:identifier ?identifier .
    ?subject schema:dateCreated ?dateCreated .
} group by ?identifier}
    ?subject schema:identifier ?identifier .
    ?subject schema:version ?version .
   ?subject schema:dateCreated ?latestDate .
 OPTIONAL {?subject schema:about/schema:name ?name .}
}
LIMIT 100`

Comment: - the idea is to use a subquery to get the latest date per identifier, then in the outer query get the resource data with that latest date

Comment: > is this your own dataset? 
yes.
> Why are the literals all strings?
it's a bug
I'll change that and came back to the thread. i hope the query above is still working. For me it looks like it will. Or is there a more performant way to do it, if i use dates?

Comment: Thanks, works well! I've changed now also the datatypes! But i've performance/memory problems filling and querying the database. That is what i've to manage now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query of UninformedUser is working well:

```
PREFIX schema: <https://schema.org/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT DISTINCT * 
{
  {
    SELECT ?identifier (max(?dateCreated) as ?latestDate) 
    WHERE {     
      ?subject rdf:type schema:CreativeWork .       
      ?subject schema:identifier ?identifier .     
      ?subject schema:dateCreated ?dateCreated . 
    } group by ?identifier
  }     
  ?subject schema:identifier ?identifier .     
  ?subject schema:version ?version .    
  ?subject schema:dateCreated ?latestDate .     
  OPTIONAL {?subject schema:about/schema:name ?name . } 
} LIMIT 100
```